# On nonlinear fractional field equations

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fractional-calculus

In a paper by Vazquez I read that an interesting variant of fractional diffusion (where the fractional operator is usually $(-\Delta)^s$) could be $(I-\Delta)^s$. Therefore I am wondering if there are results for the fractional field equation $$(I-\Delta)^s u = g(u) \quad\text{in $\mathbb{R}^N$},$$ where $0<s<1$ and $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is some nonlinear function with suitable growth conditions.

I have found only one paper dealing with the square root, namely $s=1/2$, and a few words scattered here and there. Do you have any suggestion for solving such fractional equations?

Comment: I do not know the method to deal with the special case of $s=1/2$, is there any different between $s=1/2$ and a general $s$? Can we change the differential equation to integral form by using the Fourier transform?
Then try to use the fixed point theory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will be useful:

> [Felmer, Vergara: Scalar field equation with non-local diffusion, NoDEA
>   22(2015), 1411-1428.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00030-015-0328-z)

The main result is that, when the nonlinearity $g(u)$ "behaves like $|u|^p$" with $p$ subcritical, then the equation has a solution which is Hölder-continuous, strictly positive and has exponential decay. There is also a nonexistence result for $p$ supercritical.

Comment: Would you mind describing for us in a few sentences what is in this paper?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai The main result is that, when the nonlinearity $g(u)$ "behaves like $|u|^p$" with $p$ subcritical, then the equation has a solution which is Hölder-continuous, strictly positive and has exponential decay. There is also a nonexistence result for $p$ supercritical.

Comment: I added the comment to your answer. Feel free to edit it if you do not agree.